# How to bind a function to Element loaded via Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a couple of Divs in my page with CSS class="hello"
Further I use Ajax to fetch a few more Divs with a CSS class="hello"
I have a piece of code which is called on Click event of the Divs as follows:

```
$('.hello').click(function(){
  alert("Hello Clicked");
})
```

It works fine with the Divs that are present in my page from start but does not work with Divs loaded using Ajax. Is there something I need do in order to bind this little piece of code with the newly loaded Divs too?

Comment: I agree with Joseph. Follow the link he provided and read on event delegation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you should use [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to bind the handler to another element that is already present during the execution of the binding, like say the `<body>`, or the `document` and have it detect the children events. but ideally, you should bind it to the nearest common parent of the content loaded.

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fWsY8/1/)

```
//bind to the body a "click" handler for elements that have class names of "hello"
$('body').on('click','.hello',function(){
  alert("Hello Clicked");
})
```

Comment: I got an error TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'. My guess was I am using older version of JQuery and I was right. I upgraded from 1.6.2 to 1.7.2 and now it works. Thanks.