# how to bind piece of javascript after ajax update

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wicket

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to bind a function to Element loaded via Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116170/how-to-bind-a-function-to-element-loaded-via-ajax)

in my application I want to populate an info panel onmouseover of some cell and highlight the cell so that the user can see which cell. I used the following js and css, which worked well for cells that exist when the page is first loaded

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("table1 td").hover(function(){
    $("table1 td").removeClass('highlight');
    $(this).addClass('highlight');
    });
});
```

and highlight

```
.highlight{
    border-style:outset;
    border-width:5px;
    border-color:#0000ff;
}
```

But in my application the table1 td are generated by a wicket listview and will be updated via Ajax when the user does a search. And after an Ajax update those js code had no effect. How can I make those js code still work after Ajax update? I really appreciate any help!

Comment: I think you're looking for [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: this is what your looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840149/jquery-live-event-for-added-dom-elements

Comment: Please always *search* before asking. And @Ben - quite right, though `on()` is a more up-to-date means of doing this, since they cleaned up the events API in 1.6.

Comment: Ah crap, I'm old school now..

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, if you want to use `bind` function you should use this instead. jQuery doesn't support hover.

```
$(selector).bind('mouseenter', function () {alert('hover'); });
$(selector).bind('mouseleave', function () {alert('hover'); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Ajax will update your table, so you should not write it in ready function.
here are two points:

1). Write it in Ajax success function.

```
$.ajax(function () {
....,
....,
success: funciton () {
$("table1 td").hover(function(){
$("table1 td").removeClass('highlight');
$(this).addClass('highlight');
});
}
});
```

2). Use bind function.

```
$("table1 td").bind('hover', function(){
$("table1 td").removeClass('highlight');
$(this).addClass('highlight');
});
```