# How to execute a function in javascript after an html element is loaded via AJAX without jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I need to execute a given javascript function after a part of the page is loaded via AJAX. I have no control over how the page loads so trigerring an event from the page is not an option, I suppose I'll need to check the body for the element I need and execute after this element is exists.

I saw that I could do this using jQuery ".on" method, but my jQuery version is from before this feature was introduced so I can't use it. What's the best way to do this using no third-party libraries?

Here's an example using jQuery:

```
//bind to the body a "load" handler for elements that have class names of "hello"
$('body').on('load','.hello',function(){
  alert("Hello is fully loaded, proceed with your program logic");
})
```

PS: related question that I've read before posting this one. [How to bind a function to Element loaded via Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116170/how-to-bind-a-function-to-element-loaded-via-ajax)

Comment: What version of jquery are you using?

Comment: body onload is not the same as an ajax load event or DOM Ready.

Comment: @smerny `without jquery`

Comment: You would use the AJAX call's "success" callback in this situation.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo, OP said he is using an older version of jquery and may have said "without jquery" just because he doesn't realize there is a different way to do it still using jquery.

Comment: Older versions of jQuery have `.live()`, which does what `.on` does but with slightly different syntax.

Comment: I have jQuery 1.6.2. As this is an external website I have very few things I can do and I'm by no means a knowledgeable javascript programmer. Maybe there's an easier way and I don't know. Any help is welcome.

Comment: @Barmar could you explain how to use the `.live` for this? Would suffice in my case but I'm kinda lost trying to find an example for that.

Comment: `$('body').on('load', '.hello', function...)` == `$('.hello').live('load', function...)`

Comment: Since the original version was using delegation, it might be required. If delegation is needed you'll have to use [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) instead of `live()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a function to call when the elements are loaded, and another function to check if they are loaded at an interval. Then attach the load checking function to the body's `onload` attribute. For example:

```
<body onload="checkLoaded()">

<script type="text/javascript">
    var afterLoaded = function() {
        // code to execute once elements are in place
        console.log("Elements loaded.");
    };

    var checkLoaded = function() {
        var interval = setInterval(function() {
            if(document.getElementsByClassName("hello").length) {
                clearInterval(interval);
                afterLoaded();
            }
        }, 1000);
    };
</script>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vLjsfS1cDXCm5efFmObu)

Comment: It's sorta like this. But isn't this going to be executed only once, when the body finishes loading? I need it to keep checking until the "hello" element is loaded via AJAX. If this keeps checking more than once, it solves my problem. Is this the case?

Comment: @ThiagoMoraes, if you want something to happen every time this ajax is completed successfully... why not use a callback on the ajax?

Comment: @smerny because I don't control the website. I'm just inserting a javascript tag in there without access to anything on their side. Would be a lot easier indeed, but doesn't work in my case :(

Comment: There's not an extremely efficient way to do what you're asking, but there are ways. You can use the same function I posted, wrap it in a `setInterval()` and when you find the elements you can use `clearInterval()`

Comment: @sxnine I think I'm going the setInterval way. Doesn't seem too bad considering the limitations that I have in place...

Comment: @sxnine I used the solution you proposed in your last comment in the end. If you wish to edit the body so I can accept your answer and make it clearer, just do it :)

Comment: @ThiagoMoraes I've updated the answer with an example and a working Plunker to test with.